# How to retrieve an icon of a file in Xcode (Cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, image, cocoa, directory, icons

I am creating a sort of the File Directory like a Finder in Xcode Cocoa Objc-C.

I have created a collection view with many square buttons and each button opens up a different file located in the app. What I have done until now is populated each button with the screenshots from the files (so that it would look like a Finder). However, I was wondering if is another way retrieving the icons/images of the files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSWorkspace iconForFile:fullPath];

Comment: Do you also happen to know how to assign this icon to a button?

Comment: [self.button setImage:[NSWorkspace iconForFile:fullPath]];